# resizeable: resize an element beyond the end of the screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery UI to resize elements.
I have an element that should be resizeable up to a width of e.g. 1200px or 1600px (as the user likes). But when there are elements before this one (i arranged all elements horizontally) , the resize action stops if the mouse cursor reachs the end of the screen.

You can test it here: http://gopeter.de/clients/dustin/

The very right box is resizeable.

Does anyone have any ideas how i can prevent this? 
Should i check the cursor position and extend the element when the end is reached? Or are there any other techniques?

Comment: I'm guessing the cursor just can't go outside the screen no matter what you do, unless I've missed something important ?

Comment: For sure the cursor can't go outside the screen. But if want to resize an element to a bigger size than the screen has, i run into trouble. I think it's the same phenomenon as draggable actions in regular software like the Finder of Mac OS X: you can drag an element to the top while you move your mouse cursor to the top of the screen an large lists will begin to scroll, so you can reach the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could just resize the body and scroll to allow continous resizing:

```
var body = $('body');

$('#resize').resizable({
    handles: "e,s,se",
    resize: function (event, ui) {
        var width = body.width(),
            diff = width - (width - (this.offsetLeft + this.offsetWidth));

        body.width(diff).scrollLeft(diff);
    }
});
```

or (less jQuery)

```
$('#resize').resizable({
    handles: "e,s,se",
    resize: function (event, ui) {
        var width = document.body.clientWidth,
            diff = width - (width - (this.offsetLeft + this.offsetWidth));
        document.body.style.width = diff + 'px';
        document.body.scrollLeft = diff;
    }
});
```

Here's the related fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeff_mccoy/UpmNq/2/

Note you could speed this up a little by only resizing every X number of pixels (!diff % 3) as an example but it would also be a little jerky on resize.

Comment: Great solution! You'll get the bounty in 15 hours (cause of the stackoverflow limit).

Answer (score 1):

Might be best to put the resize handle on the left.

Comment: This is a great answer, I'll upvote it for you, and everyone else surely will aswell.

Comment: ... and when the user has a screen resolution of 1366x768 and the box should be 1600px wide? Sorry that I said 1200px in my question, it was an exemplary value...